# Powershell XML parsing

Tags: loops, powershell, xml-parsing

I would like to create a Powershell script that automates parsing an XML, but collecting only certain information from it.

As it stands, right now, my script looks similar to this.

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content .\myxml.xml
$foo_sub_length = $xml.report.foos.foo.length - 1
$foo_looper = 0
$foo_looper_brackets = "[$foo_looper]"
if ($foo_sub_length -eq "") {$foo_looper_brackets = ""}
do {
    $xml.report.foos.foo$foo_looper_brackets.bar
}
while ($foo_looper -le $foo_sub_length)
```

Basically, it needs to go through and print out all of the $xml.report.foos.foo.bar values. When I run this script, I receive the error,

```
Unexpected token 'node_looper_brackets' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\notarealuser\Desktop\xmlscript.ps1:10 char:55          #not reflective of the above script
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (foo_looper_brackets:String) [], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
+     $xml.report.foos.foo$foo_looper_brackets <<<< .bar
```

Any ideas on why or how my looping is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be better off extracting this info with XPath.  If you're not using XML namespaces this is pretty trivial (and namespaces only makes it slightly harder):

```
PS> [xml]'<doc><title>Foo</title><title>Bar</title></doc>' | 
         Select-Xml '/doc/title' | Foreach {$_.Node.InnerText}

Foo
Bar
```

Comment: Hmm, any idea on how that would work for nested information? For example say there is info in doc/title/foo1/bar1/info and info in doc/title/foo1/bar2/info and doc/title/foo2/bar1/info etc...

Comment: Try an xpath expression like `'//info'`. That will find all the 'info' nodes wherever they happen to be.

Comment: So, to clarify, I would be able to do doc/title//foo//bar//info?

Comment: Not quite.  It should be like this: `... | Select-Xml '//info' | ...`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[Xml]$doc=@"
<doc><title>
<foo2><bar1><info>1</info></bar1></foo2> 
<foo1><bar1><info>2</info></bar1></foo1>
<foo1><bar2><info>3</info></bar2></foo1>
</title></doc>
"@

$doc.CreateNavigator().Select('/doc/title//info') | select value
```